# When doing a Select query how do I ignore rows of data with a certain value for a column in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have data when I query by a certain column sometimes there is more than one row returned because another column is different. Say I want to ignore certain rows when the second column is of a certain value but only when there is other values present in another row. An example is below

```
Name    Color
Tom     Blue
Tom     Red
Frank   Red
```

So say when I query under the Name column and with the value as Tom, and I get two rows back, one with the Color as a Blue and the other as Red. Say I am only interested in the color Blue so I want to ignore the row with Red as the value however only when there is more than one instance of Color per name as there is here. So if for example I queried by Name under Frank I wouldn't want to ignore the that row just because the color is Red. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: And what Color do you prefer? I mean, how to choose Blue or Red when you select Tom?

Comment: So for the example I gave it would be blue as the preferred when Tom is selected

Answer (score 3):

ROW_NUMBER colors conditionally according to priority needed, for example, if 'blue' is prefered

```
select Name,Color 
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by name order by case color
                                when 'Red' then 2 
                                when 'Blue' then 1 end) rn
from dd
) t
where rn = 1
```

When you need all but 'Red' colors except 'Red'  is the only color

```
select Name,Color 
from (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
    from (
      /* example data*/
        select 'Tom' as Name,  'Blue' as Color
        union all
        select 'Tom' ,'Red'
        union all
        select 'Tom' ,'Green'
        union all
        select 'Frank' ,'Red'
        )dd
) t
where cnt = 1 or Color !='Red'
```

Comment: Ok awesome, what if I didn't know that blue was a value. As in it could have been green, blue, orange etc, but I want those colors without knowing the actual value to be specified ranked ahead of red.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but the easy way is by limit the result to one record:

```
select Name, Color
from yourTable
where Name = 'Tom'
limit 1;
```

If you need to fetch more records, you can use a CTE to add a row number  and get those where row number = 1

```
with res as
(
    select Name, Color, row_number() over (partition by name) RN
    from yourTable
)
select Name, Color
from res
where RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking where it will only select the values that have the name of Tom and the Color of Blue.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Name = 'Tom') AND (Color = 'Blue')
```